# How do I set my nib File's Owner to an object in another nib file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib

I'm new to Cocoa and am having trouble splitting my nib file into multiple nib files.

My `MainMenu.nib` contains a `Tracker Controller` object, which is a subclass of `NSObject`. It has an outlet to a `Show Tracker` menu item in my main menu.

My `TrackerWindow.nib` has the File's Owner class set to `TrackerController`, and has outlets to the window and view in that nib file.

I'm not sure how to make the File's Owner of the second nib be a proxy for the instantiated `TrackerController` in the first nib. (I believe I need the `TrackerController` instance in the first nib so that I can use IB to set the menu item outlet.)

Am I doing it wrong? If so, how can I use IB to set outlets for the same object in multiple nib files? If not, how can I make the File's Owner of the second nib point to the `TrackerController` I've already instantiated in the first nib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is written from the perspective of an iOS developer (using view controllers).  I'm not sure how Mac OS X differs but it shouldn't be difficult to transplant the ideas.

---

The simplest way to set the File's Owner of a nib is to provide it as an argument to `loadNibNamed:owner:options:`:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Tracker" owner:trackerController options:optionsDict];
```

The snippet above assumes that `trackerController` is an instance of UIViewController.  If it isn't, use the following solution instead.

---

Instead of using `initWithNibName:bundle:`, create a `TrackerViewController` as follows (where `trackerController` is a reference to the existing TrackerController object):

```
NSDictionary *proxyDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:trackerController forKey:@"trackerController"];
NSDictionary *optionsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:proxyDict forKey:UINibExternalObjects];
TrackerViewController *trackerViewController = [[[TrackerViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Tracker" owner:trackerViewController options:optionsDict];
// Display trackerViewController
```

Create an External Object with an Identifier of `trackerController` in Tracker.nib and connect your outlets/actions to this object.

Comment: Thanks, that set me on the right path! As I had already instantiated a `trackerController` in my `MainMenu.nib`, I used the following: `[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"TrackerWindow" owner:self.trackerController];`.