# ArrayController cannot find AppDelegate (Bindings in Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appdelegate, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I am just starting to learn about bindings. In the tutorials I have found, someone is connecting an ArrayController to AppDelegate by simply picking AppDelegate from the list that can be found under the bindings-options of the ArrayController. When I try to do the same, AppDelegate is not included in the list.

What am I doing wrong here? (I am usingh objective-c btw)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have selected the correct object i.e. ArrayController.

Please refer the screen shot:
[image]

FYI, check if you missed something from these steps:

Step 1: Create an instance of ArrayController under Objects section.

Step 2: Select it, and go to the Binding Inspector.

Step 3: In Controller Content, select Content Array's Bind To.

Step 4: In this pop up you could see, as shown above.

---

**Or, other cases may be you have created a new Window in your project. There you can not see the AppDelegate.**

In such case set the File's Owner's class to AppDelegate or some other class from where you want to pick the array.

[image]

Then select the array controller and set in content to File's Owner.

[image]

Note: In the screen shots I am using View-based table view.

Comment: hey thanks a lot. i have done all of this though. these are the exact steps the tutorial goes through, but it's not there.

Comment: @chrisnolten: check my updated answer, and tell if you can get something.

Comment: thanks. i have not created a new window, i am using the main window. i can still try this though?

Comment: @chrisnolten: email your project. vaidya.anoop@gmail.com

Comment: That "App Delegate" object only appears in single-coordinator apps, and only should be in the main nib for even for those.  For other types of apps and for other nibs, you can bind through the application with a keypath beginning with `delegate`.   [It is not possible to safely create the App Delegate object in other nibs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132282/objective-c-all-instances-for-ui-is-nil/23139182#23139182).